# Can I Use the List Comprehensions for taking input in the 2D Array in the python ??. And how it can be implemented for the nD array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Suppose The user wants to give an input below format.

[image: Format of the User Input]

How to take this input in the 2D array? And what is the **general rule of List comprehension for the nD** (n = Natural Number) Array??
Please Suggest, Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 4    
a = [[int(input()) for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way:

```
out = []
for i in range(n):
    temp = list(map(int,input().split()))
    #temp will be [1,1,1,0,0,0] in the first iteration
    out.append(temp)
```

Out will be in the following way:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 0], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a loop for that.

```
user_input = []
while True:
    row = input('Next row:\n')
    if len(row) == 0:
        break
    user_input.append([int(x) for x in row.split()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but you have to know the number of dimensions in advance.
Like for 2D 4x4:

```
a=[[int(input()) for x in range(4)] for y in range(4)]
```

The 4-s could be anything, but the nesting itself is fixed in such code.

For arbitrary number of dimensions you can try a bit of recursion:

```
def nd(dims):
  if len(dims) == 0:
    return int(input())
  return [nd(dims[:-1]) for x in range(dims[-1])]
```

and run it like

```
>>> nd([2,2])
1
2
3
4
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

for 2x2 2D
or

```
>>> nd([2,3,4])
1
2
3
[...]
23
24
[[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], [[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]], [[13, 14], [15, 16], [17, 18]], [[19, 20], [21, 22], [23, 24]]]
```

for 2x3x4 3D.